# USBC CC lines connection for DRP with dead battery support

Tags: usb, usb-c

I would like to implement a simple DRP without PD controller that supports dead-battery mode.

At first I used MOSFETs to switch Rd or Rp resistors on the CC lines depending on whether I needed it to be to be SRC of SINK, like in page 21 of this [application note from ST](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/group1/38/94/1d/41/0e/ba/49/21/DM00536349/files/DM00536349.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00536349.pdf).

I ran into an issue with the dead-battery mode: it needed energy to activate the Rd resistors.

I think the following schematic can work, with the bonus of only switching on the M1 transistor and still be able to detect if a SRC or SINK is attached. If the CC line voltage rises it is a SRC, and if it goes down it is a SINK.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcvqSI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In most schematics there are only resistors, but according to the [USBC specification](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB%20Type-C%20Spec%20R2.0%20-%20August%202019.pdf) on page 241 the most important is the voltage of the CC pin.

What do you think of it? Is it a good idea or do I completely miss how USBC works?

Comment: How are you planning to detect insertions in order to provide vbus? The extra resistor makes the voltage range where something is inserted smaller. Better is just depletion mode mosfets

Comment: With and ADC. When M1 is activated the CC line will be at 0.8V. When a SYNC is attached it will add a 5.1k pull down and drop to 0.4V. If a SRC is attached it will rise to over 1V.